# Delete directory from batch without recycle bin

Tags: batch-file, command, delete-file

I need a small help to delete directory from batch.

I use the command :

```
RD /S /Q /K c:\MyDirectory
```

But the system move this directory in the recycle bin, I don't want this.
I saw that the option is /k :
http://jpsoft.com/help/del.htm

But I have this error :

> Invalid switch - "K"

I don't understand why.. Any Ideas ?

Comment: In fact, the directory to delete is on NAS

Comment: You will need to configure the NAS not to use the recycle bin on the device.

Answer (score 2):

`RD` will bypass the recycle bin.

JPsoft writes a third party cmd replacement, which has extra features.